# How to limit the number of request that get access to an instance?

Tags: java

I have a web application with Java server, and the Java application is getting requests from the web.

The problem is that there is an instance of an object that can handle only one request each time, and the web requests are coming before the object finishing its job.

How do I create some sort of "connection pool" for these requests? Or is there any other way that I can limit the access to this object instance?

I am using the synchronized declaration at some method, and it is doing a pretty good job, but the problem is that its is not ordered. How can I control the order of the incoming requests for this method?

Comment: Rethink your design. Limiting requests (while possible) will be bad for performance.

Comment: You could implement a basic object pool. Apache has [commons pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) which should help.

Comment: Synchronization. Semaphores. Redesign so there isn't a single object. Too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to synchronize the method that is shared by all the request thread by using synchronized keyword.
The drawback of this is that it will affect your performances. 
SO TRY to keep the synchronized block small.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the requests as commands and store them on a queue and process them 1 by 1. This has however consequences for the user (as already mentioned before) that the response time will increase. To overcome this a bit the handling of the command might be done asynchronously, meaning that the user will invoke the command and get a answer back that the command was received correctly. Once the server is done with handling the command the server can call back the user notifying him that the command is (successfully) processed.

Note that this can become a complex solution and it might be better to check whether you can't remove/refactor the singleton.